# ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

Environment information (`cat /proc/cpuinfo`):

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : 000e
Serial          : 00000000ed794a6d
```

I'm trying to run [MJPG Streamer](https://github.com/alexszilagyi/mjpg-streamer) for [PiCamera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/) and I'm getting:

```
MJPG Streamer Version.: 2.0
 i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0
 i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
 i: Frames Per Second.: 10
 i: Format............: JPEG
 i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT
ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
 Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
 i: init_VideoIn failed
```

The command used for run is:

```
mjpg_streamer -i input_uvc.so -o output_http.so
```

What could be the issue?

Is that I have a [PiCamera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/) that runs on a `Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2` ?

Is [PiCamera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/) compatibile with this model of the `Raspberry Pi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the bcm2835 Video4Linux driver module.

Load it with:
modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

To make it load on boot, add add bcm2835-v4l2 into /etc/modules