# Pi Camera V2: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory

Tags: camera, picamera

Environment info:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 108.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware        : BCM2711
Revision        : d03114
Serial          : 100000006d862baa
Model           : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

While trying to run MJPG Streamer for my Pi Camera V2, I run this command:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so" -o "./output_http.so"
```

But I get this error:

```
MJPG Streamer Version: git rev: 85f89a8c321e799fabb1693c5d133f3fb48ee748
 i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0
 i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
 i: Frames Per Second.: -1
 i: Format............: JPEG
 i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT
ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
 i: init_VideoIn failed
```

What might be the problem?  I saw [another post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77768/error-opening-v4l-interface-no-such-file-or-directory) here for the same issue which was solved by loading the correct Video4Linux driver for that user's cpu, but mine is different.

I'm basically following [this guide](https://community.octoprint.org/t/setting-up-octoprint-on-a-raspberry-pi-running-raspbian/2337) and everything has gone perfectly besides the camera.

This Pi model was just released so perhaps it is not yet compatible with the camera? :(

**Update - inclidng dmesg output below, looks fine?

```
[    4.715228] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.747167] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    4.761076] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
[    4.824408] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.826818] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.835560] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.840312] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.843638] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.865337] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[    4.865698] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    4.865762] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    4.866295] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[    4.866707] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[    4.867016] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[    4.867040] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    4.867060] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    4.867079] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    4.867097] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    4.867291] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[    4.879957] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    4.879999] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    4.893993] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    4.894048] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
```

Comment: Have you loaded the V4L2 module `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like I have that module?

modprobe: FATAL: Module bcm2835-v412 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.51-v7l+

Comment: Ah, I needed an underscore instead of a dash.  Unfortunately though, even after successfully loading the module I get the same error.

Comment: Look with a `dmesg` command to see what happened when you tried to load the module.

Comment: Just added the dmesg output to the post, looks ok?  I'm starting to think maybe I have a physical i.e cable issue or perhaps a bum camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As embarrassing as it is to admit, my problem was that I had the ribbon cable plugged into the "display" port on the board rather than the "camera".  Thanks to everyone who took the time to read or comment.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer. You may have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back. Your comment made me realize there were two different ribbon cable ports. I made the same mistake.